# Swift: How to use for-in loop with an optional?

Tags: swift2, option-type, for-in-loop

What's the proper way to use for-in loop with an optional?

Right now I always perform an optional binding before looping it.  Are there other idioms?

```
let optionalInt:[Int]? = [1, 2, 3]

if let optionalInt = optionalInt {
  for i in optionalInt {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 54):

If set of operations to be applied to all elements of the array, it is possible to replace for-loop with `forEach{}` closure and use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

```
var arr: [Int]? = [1, 2, 3]
arr?.forEach{print($0)}
```

Comment: No, it's not the only answer. However, it's the shortest one.

Comment: Note that you cannot break on a forEach.

Comment: Note you cannot do a forEach if the loop is part of an object's initialization logic, since self can't be captured by a closure before self is initialized.

Comment: This also adds unnecessary memory and performance footprint

Comment: Memory and performance footprint are the same if not similar. If you'd like to reduce memory footprint, consider using autoreleasepool in for loops: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

Answer (score 24):

I don't think there's a proper way. There are many different ways, it really comes down to what you prefer, Swift is full of features that can make your program look really nice as per your choosing.

Here are some ways I could think of:

```
let optionalInt:[Int]? = [1, 2, 3]

for i in optionalInt! { print(i) }

for i in optionalInt ?? [] { print(i) }

for i in optionalInt as [Int]! {  print(i) }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can write this one:

```
let optionalInt:[Int]? = [1, 2, 3]
for i in optionalInt ?? [Int]() {
    print(i)
}
```

But I'd recommend you avoid using optional value, for instance you can write like this:

```
var values = [Int]()
// now you may set or may not set 
for i in values {
    print(i)
}
```

Or if you want to use optional value and this code calls in a function can use `guard`:

```
guard let values = optionalInt else { return }
for i in values {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: `for i in optionalInt ?? [Int]()` is extra `for i in optionalInt ?? []` is enough

Answer (score 5):

the cleanest solution is sometimes the most basic one

```
if let a = myOptionalArray {
    for i in a {
        
    }
}
```

so i would suggest, keep your approach

the approaches above only insert an empty option, or the forEach creates a block just because `if let a = optional {` isn't sexi enough

Answer (score 0):

I'm two years late but I think this is the best way.

```
func maybe<T>(risk: T?, backup: T) -> T {
  return risk.maybe(backup)
}
```

and

```
extension Optional {
   func maybe(_ backup: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
     switch self {
     case let .some(val):
        return val
     case .none:
        return backup
     }
   }
}
```

and now

```
for i in optionalInt.maybe([]) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: LOL? `for i in optionalInt ?? [] { print(i) }'

Comment: ha! killing a mosquito with a canon

Comment: wau, I just think sometimes, and what was wrong with objective-c nil behaviour ? We are back into how to loop simple array and don't write boilerplate... Ah I forgot , swift designers just need to be different haha

Comment: How many people scratch their heads before realizing it's a joke?